# $x, g \in G \rightarrow |x| = |g^{-1}xg|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $x, g \in G$ where $G$ is a group and let $|h|$ denote the order of an element $h \in G$. Show that $|x| = |g^{-1}xg|$, and conclude that $a, b \in G \rightarrow |ab| = |ba|$.

Does anyone have a get-started hint or two, keeping in mind this is for a first class in algebra?

Comment: Do you know that the map $x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$ is an automorphism of $G$?

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for the response. Is it a common notation in English for the order of an element? In French, we usually use $\operatorname{ord}(a)$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, An interesting piece of information. At least I can tell that I have seen this practice a couple of times in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

1. $x^n=1$ if and only if $(g^{-1}xg)^n=1$
2. $ba=a^{-1}(ab)a$